# После компиляции выводится что то не понятное

Tags: java, intellij-idea

На кодировке `utf-8`, у меня, после того как я компилирую, выводится что-то системное и после него уже следует сам результат выполнения кода. Вот что выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот то, что хотелось бы видеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И  то, это не чистый вывод компилятора, мне функция `SnapShooter` помогает убрать все то, что выводится на 1 скрине.  По идее должно выводится просто "Успешно получили синтезатор" Вообщем как убрать все системное что на 1 скрине, без функции `SnapShooter`? (кстати, что это за функция?)
Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Не помню точно, есть ли такое в Idea, а именно - фильтры либо выбор того, что выводить в консоль(системные сообщения либо сразу результат)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль на первом и втором скринах полностью одинаковая. 
Текст в консоли начинается с выполняемой комманды. В первом случае она приведена полностью, а во втором в сокращенном виде.
Обратите внимание, что сокращенный вариант завершен троеточием. Если вы нажмете мышкой на сокращенный вариант, ваша консоль станет выглядеть в точности также, как и на первом скрине

Comment: Да, я вижу. Но в 1 варианте я не смог сделать такой же сокращенный вариант, как во втором скриншоте.

Comment: Команда сворачивается для экономии места на мониторе. После того, как развернули, повторное сворачивание не предусмотрено. Могу ошибаться.